# how to detect if a type is an iterator or const_iterator

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, metaprogramming

I'm wondering, if there is a way to check at compile time whether a type T of some iterator type is a const_iterator, or not. Is there some difference in the types that iterators define (value_type, pointer, ...) between iterators and const iterators?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
typedef std::vector<int> T;

is_const_iterator<T::iterator>::value       // is false
is_const_iterator<T::const_iterator>::value // is true
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

C++03 Solution:

As none of the answer seems correct, here is my attempt which is working with GCC:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_const_pointer { static const bool value = false; };

template<typename T>
struct is_const_pointer<const T*> { static const bool value = true; };

template <typename TIterator>
struct is_const_iterator
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::pointer pointer;
    static const bool value = is_const_pointer<pointer>::value;
};
```

Example:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator it_type;
    typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator const_it_type;

    std::cout << (is_const_iterator<it_type>::value) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (is_const_iterator<const_it_type>::value) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Online Demo : http://ideone.com/TFYcW

Comment: Is it just me or has there been a lack in community upvotes lately? :( +1 you said its working, it looks good

Comment: I've selected your answer, as your solution uses the std::iterator_traits<> class

Comment: Doesn't work when `std::iterator_traits<I>::pointer` is a proxy class type.  But if there is a solution for that case, it would have to use some pretty nasty SFINAE.

Comment: That's why I used `reference`, which is sort of guaranteed not to be a proxy. Good point with the `iterator_traits` though.

Comment: @SimonRichter `reference` is a proxy in e.g. `std::vector<bool>` and other "container-like" things.

Answer (score 6):

C++11

```
template<class IT, class T=decltype(*std::declval<IT>())>    
constexpr bool  
is_const_iterator() {   
        return  ! std::is_assignable <
                decltype( *std::declval<IT>() ),
                T   
        >::value;
}
```

Comment: This goes to the heart of the constness of a const_iterator - you can't assign to the thing returned from dereferencing the iterator.  This may be the only answer that works for oddballs like vector<bool>.  (Of course, it doesn't check if it is an iterator, or is dereferencible, but the OP was assuming it was an iterator of some sort.  But to call it "is_const_iterator" it should probably check both the const-ness and the iterator-ness...)

Comment: I don't think this will work correctly if the type T represented by the iterator has it's assignment operators deleted.

Answer (score 5):

One method that works at least on gcc is via the *reference* typedef:

```
struct true_type { };
struct false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct is_const_reference
{
    typedef false_type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_const_reference<T const &>
{
    typedef true_type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_const_iterator
{
    typedef typename is_const_reference<
        typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference>::type type;
};
```

You can verify that it works by using

```
inline bool test_internal(true_type)
{
    return true;
}

inline bool test_internal(false_type)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
bool test(T const &)
{
    return test_internal(typename is_const_iterator<T>::type());
}

bool this_should_return_false(void)
{
    std::list<int> l;
    return test(l.begin());
}

bool this_should_return_true(void)
{
    std::list<int> const l;
    return test(l.begin());
}
```

With a sufficiently high optimization level, the last two functions should be reduced to `return false;` and `return true;`, respectively. At least they do for me.

Comment: Have you tested it? Does `iterator` type has `reference` type? Post a working code to ideone!

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the disassembler output, and saw that the test functions do indeed return the desired result, as a constant. I use types to denote true and false here, in principle you could also use `static` `const` members and achieve the same effect.

Comment: I'm referring to this syntax `typename T::reference`. How can you write this when type of `l.begin()` can be either `iterator` or `const_iterator` which is actually `T` in your syntax. So my question is: how can `iterator::reference` work? Have you tested it? please post a working code on www.ideone.com.

Comment: I admit to being lazy here -- `typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference` would have been more correct. For the non-specialized case this is a typedef pointing to `typename T::reference`, which appears to be the convention for iterator types.

Comment: I've added the use of `std::iterator_traits` and uploaded the result [here](http://ideone.com/jf4hQ).

Answer (score 5):

With C++11, the new standard header `<type_traits>` provides `std::is_const<T>`,
so Nawaz's solution can be simplified:

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct is_const_iterator
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer pointer; 
    static const bool value = 
        std::is_const<typename std::remove_pointer<pointer>::type>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky because you have to pass `T` itself but it works (template specialization, g++ 4.4.5):

```
template<typename T, typename S>
struct is_const_iterator {
    enum {
        value = false
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct is_const_iterator<T, typename T::const_iterator> {
    enum {
        value = true
    };
};
```

Use like this:

```
typedef std::vector<int> T;
is_const_iterator<T, T::iterator>::value           //is false
is_const_iterator<T, T::const_iterator>::value     //is true
```

Comment: It requires you to pass the container type also. So not a solution, in my opinion!