# Declare a container const or non-const depending on iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

Suppose that I have the following function:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void f()
{
    std::list<int> numList;
    Iterator it = numList.begin();
    ...
}
```

`Iterator` can be either `std::list<int>::iterator` or `std::list<int>::const_iterator`.

The above function compiles for `std::list<int>::iterator`, but for `std::list<int>::const_iterator` the list should be declared as `const std::list<int>`.

Is there a way to declare the type of the list either `std::list<int>` or `const std::list<int>` depending on whether `Iterator` is `iterator` or `const_iterator`?

Comment: why should it be declared as `const std::list<int>`? Is it a requirement by you? Because you can obtain a `const_iterator` from a non-const list.

Comment: OK. But they are obtained with different functions: `begin()` and `cbegin()`. How to get either an `iterator` or a `const_iterator` from a non-const list?

Comment: A `const_iterator` should be convertible to an `iterator`, so just use `cbegin`.

Comment: Wait, the other way around. Why do you have the template parameter as either const or non const iterator? A bit more of what you intend would help finding a solution.

Comment: look here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2787500#2787500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible by using `std::iterator_traits`, `<type_traits>` and `std::conditional`, something similar to

```
using pointer_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer;
using list_type = typename std::conditional<std::is_const<pointer_type>::value, const std::list<int>, std::list<int>>::type;

list_type numList;
```

Mind this is untested so you should probably adjust it a little bit, it's just to give you the basic idea behind this. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423246/how-to-detect-if-a-type-is-an-iterator-or-const-iterator) answer too.